# Is it possible to disable the ability to save results and/or export query results in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

Is it possible to disable the ability to use the "Save Results" (see attached image) feature in the Google BigQuery UI for specific users? I can see that we can disable exports through a role permission but can't seem to find a way to disable this functionality for users.

[image]

Comment: Supposing that it wasn't possible to download the results, you could still just copy and paste them. If it wasn't possible to copy and paste them, you could take a screenshot. What does disabling the download button accomplish?

Comment: @ElliottBrossard that is true however when querying and returning millions or even hundreds of thousands of rows of data, it is very unlikely someone will be able to copy the data that way. If we could disable the ability to save the results to anything other than another BigQuery table, we can limit the ability for individual users to export very large amounts of data out of the warehouse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to disable this option in BigQuery. Every user that can run a query is able to save the results.

The most you can do to limit users from specific data is to create [BigQuery Views](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/views-intro) of the tables. By creating views you can limit the access to specific columns and fields.

You have to create the views in a new dataset for which you will provide viewing permission to the users you want, while cutting them off from the original tables. This way, they will be able to query only the views and be able to save these query results without having access to the sensitive parts of the original tables.