# Allow to run queries on BQ and explore data on Data Studio but remove CSV export

Tags: google-bigquery, google-iam

I would like to have an IaM role/custom role that allows user to run queries, explore the data through Data Studio but prevent them from exporting the data to CSV.
Is there a way to achieve this ?

I have tried removing the bigquery.tables.export permissions but the user can still export the data to CSV.

Any thoughts ?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to disable the ability to save results and/or export query results in BigQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57259476/is-it-possible-to-disable-the-ability-to-save-results-and-or-export-query-result)

Comment: No, it is not possible to limit the export rights. If your users only work in Data/Looker Studio, they do not need any access to BigQuery, if you own all data set in Looker Studio and "pay" their queries. However, even Looker Studio let the user export any data from a graph to a csv-file.

Comment: @blackbishop I think this must be outdated as I managed to restrict the export to CSV while still allowing to do queries however it prevented any exploration in Looker Studio as well

Answer (score 1):

As @Samuel mentioned in the comments:

No, it is not possible to limit the export rights. If your users only work in **Data/Looker Studio**, they do not need any access to `BigQuery` if you own all data set in **Looker Studio** and "pay" their queries.

However, even **Looker Studio** let the user export any data from a graph to a `csv-file`.

Posting the answer as *community wiki* for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future.

Feel free to edit this answer for additional information.